What's the name of this horror movie about an infected animal?
I watched a movie around 15 years ago about a creature which in the first scene could not be seen but it was captured by some animal traffickers that were trying to run away Indigenous peoples. And then I remember an old lady was infected because she was bitten by that creature indirectly. and she was the mother of a dude which form a relationship with a girl.
And previously, the girl was told by a lady which she was fortune-telling playing cards. she was telling her of a great future where she will meet her true love but warned of a bad event i.e. the mother's sickness. I think I remember seeing the mother getting worse as the movie was progressing to the point of a scene where she is trying to eat a dead dog.
I know it's not much but this is all I remember.

You're describing the plot of Peter Jackson's Braindead (AKA Dead Alive) from 1992.

In 1957, a zoologist traps a rare Sumatran rat-monkey on Skull Island and brings it back to New Zealand with the locals hot on his trail. Later, a young man falls in love and takes the young woman to the zoo. His overbearing and disapproving mother follows them and gets bitten by the rat-monkey. The monkey's bite turns her into a zombie, and her doting son has to keep her and the others she's bitten tranquilized in the basement while trying to preserve his love life. 

It's often considered as one of the grossest (yet funniest) horror movies ever made. Here's the trailer:




Yes, finally I know the name of this movie.

It's best to go for the unrated version, though (unless you're not into gore!)
